# How do I compute a row value out of the column name and another column value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to coding and wish to simplify some processes at my workplace -

My Dataframe is as below:

| 1 Oct | 1 Nov | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NA | NA | 1 Oct |
| NA | NA | 1 Nov |

I wish to attribute a value of 1 where the column header matches the row as follows:

| 1 Oct | 1 Nov | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Null | 1 Oct |
| Null | 1 | 1 Nov |

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
for col in df.columns[:-1]:
    df[col] = np.where((df.Date==col),1,"Null")
```

---

**df:**

```
    1 Oct   1 Nov   Date
0   1       Null    1 Oct
1   Null    1       1 Nov
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be using `crosstab`

```
>>> pd.crosstab(df[df.columns[:-1]], df.Date).set_index(df.columns[:-1])

Date   1 Nov  1 Oct
1 Oct      1      0
1 Nov      0      1
```